# How to make html-clean not to remove <script> tags

Tags: jquery, html

I am writing a documentation and want to add some Formatted HTML. I use htmlClean for HTML formatting ([link](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-clean/)). I do this in following way:

HTML Code:

```
<pre>
    <div> Some more HTML code here </div>
</pre>
```

JS:

```
var entityMap = {
        "&": "&amp;",
        "<": "&lt;",
        ">": "&gt;",
        '"': '&quot;',
        "'": '&#39;',
        "/": '&#x2F;'
    };

    function htmlEncode(string) {
        return String(string).replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function (s) {
            return entityMap[s];
        });
    }

$("pre").each(function () {
        var code = $(this).html();
        $(this).empty();
        code = $.htmlClean(code, {
            format: true,
            formatIndent: 0
        })
        //code = htmlEncode(code)
        $(this).html(code);
    });
```

It works perfectly. The issue is when I want have a script tags inside formatted code like this:

```
<pre>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabs-accordions.min.js"></script>
</pre>
```

Result is empty field and I have no idea why. I have tried to debug it with no success.

Please be so kind and suggest a solution or maybe a better JS HTML formatting script could be a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation in the link you provided there is an option called "allowedTags". Thus you have to pass that option to $.htmlClean;

```
$.htmlClean(code, {
    allowedTags: ["pre", "script"],
    format: true,
    formatIndent: 0
});
```

Hope this answer is useful. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabs-accordions.min.js">&nbsp;
</script>
```

i use the [jquery.clean](https://github.com/MrAntix/jquery-clean) version is 1.4.2